# How to combine chunks of binary data into a single composite file

Tags: file, go

On my server, I have large files that have been split into smaller (binary) chunks. The chunks are stored with their number: `chunk0, chunk1, chunk2...`

The number is the position of the chunk sequentially in the large file.

They are stored in a directory that has the same name as the file they make up. (In actuality, the directory has the large-file's hash as its name).

```
        [ chunk0 (1MB)
        | chunk1 (1MB)
        | chunk2 (1MB)
file1/ -| chunk3 ..
        | chunk4 ..
        | chunk5 ..
        [ chunk6 ..
```

So `file1` would be a 6 MB composite file.

The server is written in Go and so is the client.

I want to provide the user a way of downloading a large file without having to download each chunk separately.

Something along the lines of:

1. client sends a request to the server API for `file1`
2. **server provides the full `file1` data from the chunks**
3. client downloads the file data to a single file

So the question is, how to do step 2? I would like to reassemble the chunks on the fly - when the user requests a certain file (without creating any new files). Another caveat is that it needs to be fast as possible because the application I am working on is oriented around speed.

Something like the functionality of a [blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) would be good I think? But this project is in Go and using a browser or JavaScript is not an option.

Comment: Show what you tried so far and describe the problem you encountered. Is "their file hash" a hash of the file contents or the file name?   Why not respond directly with the file on the first request?

Comment: I would consider using a [`io.MultiReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader) to easily combine the individual readers, and then utilise [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to write the concatenated chunks to the client.

Comment: @CeriseLimón sorry, it's a hash of the chunk file contents. And yes, responding directly with a file on the first request could be done too - whatever works best. The only reason I've given an extra step, is to perhaps give the server a chance to create a new endpoint for a file.

Comment: How does the application find the chunks given a file name?

Comment: @CeriseLimón the composite file is given an ID and the chunks are related to it in an SQL database

Comment: The basic approach is to write the files  in sequence to a [response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter).  You do not describe in sufficient detail how to find those files given a request.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can easily concatenate files on the go (without having to do any on-disk file operations) by writing the contents of multiple `io.Readers` into a single `io.Writer`. The buffering behind these abstractions will take care of the rest for you.

The key things you need are

- [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)
- [`os.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) which returns an `io.Reader`
- The fact that the [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/http/#ResponseWriter) is an `io.Writer`

So, a general scheme for step 2 could be, in your `http.Handler`:

```
Set Content-Type header
Determine file chunk names in whole file
Check all chunks are accessible 
For each chunk file in order
  Open chunk file
  Copy contents of file to w ResponseWriter
  Close file
```

I added a pre check for file access there because you don't want to be in the middle of sending the file when you detect that you've an error condition. At that time it's too late to set an appropriate error code.

This operation will be completely IO-bound, either disk or network throughput will be the limiting factor, so a serial approach is likely to be as good as it gets (if you're considering a single server process in a single machine).

As stated in the comments by **@Emile Pels**, an `io.MultiReader` allows you to concatenate multiple Readers, so with that you can replace the entire for loop with:

```
Create a slice of opened files in order
Create io.MultiReader(files...)
io.Copy(w, mreader)
Close each open file
```

One downside I can think of with that would be that it forces you to open all the files and keep them open for the duration of the operation, which under high load, large file size and a high chunks-per-file factor could lead to your process exceeding it's open file descriptor limit.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think so.
I can think the `MultiReader` version reaching the OS's open file descriptor limit if there are very many chunks per file and many of these split up files are being served concurrently. Happens because all those files are kept open for the duration of the whole operation. So that's a con right there.
You'd definitely need some error handling in both, in case one of the files isn't present, and the `MultiReader` one naturally lets you detect that before doing any processing. So I'd add a `check all files exist` step before the loop in the first one.

Comment: @Depp have updated my answer in response to your edits.